# What is the industry best practice for when 3rd parties are hit with ransomware?

Tags: network, ransomware, third-party

I am interested to know if anyone has experienced this, what was the response and more importantly, **is there best practices to handle these situations**?

My organization recently had a case where one of our many vendors was unfortunately hit by Ransomware (Ryuk). Some of their users have access to our systems (VPN users).

The reaction was pretty much, cut all connections with the vendor (VPN, Email, SFTP, etc) thus actually causing a business harm to us as well.

Although I understand the response, I did feel it was a little overkill (akin to 
"Pull all the Ethernet cables out" after adware was found).

Logically, the detonation of Ransomware would be a final step in a list of "Objective on Target" due to its high visibility by the blue team. If they ran it as soon as they got in, then their only objective is to make money. If it was the final step in a long list of objectives, that included the infiltration of customers networks then they were already in our systems thus making the disconnection of VPN mute.

I feel a better course would be a review of the user profile that is granted to their users to ensure least privilege is enforced and a review of the user activity of those accounts (around 30-50 max)

Emails with attachments can be sent to quarantine for review.

SFTP files can be scanned to ensure they are not infected.

**Is complete disconnection a normal response in these type of events?**

Comment: My _opinion_ on dealing with ransomware is: Hunker down in a bunker that's sealed off from everything, and be prepared to nuke everything and restore from backups.  Even though I don't think you'll find many people suggesting that you play around with malware, and the most repeated movie line around here is "Take off and nuke it from orbit; it's the only way to be sure", that's still all just opinion based and not an answer to questions on this site.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say it is overkill, since you're going to be exposed to the Internet and external connections and thus be constantly under drive-by attacks or targeted.  However, it is certainly a good idea to consider the vendor 'higher risk'.

Regular security reviews should always be undertaken and the principle of least privilege is definitely something which should always be considered during this.  As a first step, all credentials and keys should be immediately revoked, and should not be re-enabled until an audit has taken place to prove there is no infection or unauthorised access to the vendor.

The vendor having VPN access to your network and the risk that exposes you to could vary massively - it might be access to your internal website through to control of critical infrastructure.  If it's the latter, then you should certainly consider curtailing that, monitor the systems closely, and not allow access again until a full independent audit has taken place.  If it's just read access as a non-privileged user then the risk is minimal, apart from of course information leakage, unless there is serious issues in server infrastructure.

I would not allow any file uploads from the third party again until that audit has taken place - you should already be scanning the uploads though.  I would also take the opportunity to examine what protocols they do have access to; is it just SFTP, or are there shared hosting services like Dropbox involved, and if so, why?

I would also require all e-mails for some time to be passed through and signed off manually by IT administrators before being forwarded to their final destination.

If this was a company involved in any way with my IT infrastructure and network I would immediately be looking for a replacement vendor in the medium-long term.  From a business perspective, you mention there is lost business associated with cutting off this vendor but all the above will also cost money and time to implement.  That figure of course depends on how good your existing policies are - if I'm setting something up there wouldn't be much to change ;) !